# How to make doxygen display member function description in the group?

Tags: doxygen

I use doxygen to generate pdf documents，In one file, I have a bunch of public functions that I want to put in a group. I do this as follows:

```
/**
* @biref xxxx
* @file demo.h
* @defgroup my_group this is my group
*/

/**
    @addtogroup my_group
    @{
*/

//CODE & STUFF WITH DOCUMENTATION

/**
   @}
*/
```

The issue is that in the "Module Documentation", only the name of the class is included, no member functions are included. And then clicking on the class name will jump to "File Documentation" section, there are member functions are.

How can i make the "Module Documentation" include description of member function?

Comment: which version of doxygen are you using? can you enlarge your example slightly with one or two functions? In the example there is nor trace of a class whilst you mention this in the text, please explain. Also give the settings used that are different from the default settings (i.e. the result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`)